# geom_line plot with colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to draw count vs countries line plot and add color as variant_type. But the output of code below is not as desired.

Also, how do I rotate my x-ticks by 90 degrees?

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)

countries <- c("America", "Brazil", "Canada", "America", "Brazil", "Canada")
count <- c(1, 2, 3, 2.5, 3, 4.5)
variant_type <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")

tbl <- tibble(countries, count, variant_type)

ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = countries,
           y = count),
           color = variant_type) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        aspect.ratio = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

Comment: ... and put `color=variant_type` inside your call to `aes()`.

Comment: The countries and the variant_type do not agree with one another, one of the segment end points will be of one color and the other of another one.